# Is it possible to find the salt used when hashing?

Tags: hash, salt

I know what the hashing algorithm is (FNV-1a). I'm also sure that the hash constant is "2166136261u". I have a handful of seeds that was hashed and the outcome of hashing the seed. I'm only missing the salt that was used. Is it possible to find the salt used when seed is hashed?

Comment: Depends on the hashing algorithm. If it's an algorithm worth its salt (see what I did there?), it shouldn't be possible.

Comment: i updated post to include which algorithm I'm using. Good pun lol!

Comment: It's a relatively fast algorithm, so brute forcing is always an option. Even more so if you know the size of the salt and it's relatively small.

Comment: well i don't mine letting my pc run for a bit if it is possible. thanks for responding.

Comment: How big is the hash? FNV-1a is a family of hashes of different lengths? How big is the salt? If the salt is large enough you may not be able to find *the* salt but you may be able to find an *equivalent* salt.

Comment: I'm sure this is the hash constant..  const uint32_t FNV_init = 2166136261u